# Stream is closed when accessing resources file from a library jar file

Tags: java

I have a project that has this structure and I call this as LIBRARY jar file..I packaged it as a jar file..

```
/src/main/java
    /src/main/resources/files.yaml

public class DataManager {

    public static String FILE = "files.yaml";

    public Optional<Object> getFiles(String code) throws YAMLException {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File featureFile = new File(getFile());
        if (featureFile.exists()) {
            logger.info("Feature file is present!!!");
        } else {
            // This is called
            logger.info("Feature file NOT PRESENT!!!");
        }

        try (InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(getFile())) {
            //Stream is closed at this point
            yaml.load(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new YAMLException("Unable to read  file", e);
        }

        return Optional.empty();

    }

    protected String getFile() {
        return FILE;
    }

}
```

Now, in my MAIN project..I am referencing that LIBRARY jar file

```
public class Main {
    public void getSomething(String code) throws YAMLException {

        DataManager manager = new DataManager();
        manager.getFiles("SAMPLE");
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    }
}
```

When I call my DataManager from my main class, I am getting stream is closed and I think it cannot find the file.
I have used classloader to fetch the file for me but it seems that I might be doing something.

I did a `jar tvf library.jar` and I saw that my config file "files.yaml" are packaged in my library jar file.  What could be wrong?

**UPDATE 2**
What is weird is that, I tried to read the file using buffered reader.

```
InputStream ins = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(getFile());
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// It prints the values of the yml files
```

And it was able to read the file.. so I am not sure why using my first code is not working but using bufferedreader works.  Any idea?

Comment: Seems weird since `BufferedReader` is just a wrapper around same `InputStream` object and you would have same problem with it. You might get different results depending on the fact how you run your "main" jar. Is it main class trough IDE directly? Or you run `.jar` with IDE? Or you ran `.jar` with `java` command line?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you gettin `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` because input stream object is `null`:

```
 try (InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(getFile())) { // in == null
      . . .
      yaml.load(in); // exception here
 }
```

What is strange, that I reproduced your setup and I don't have a problem that you described.

My setup is:

"Main" jar content:

```
/com/example/Main.class
```

"Dependency" jar:

```
/com/example/DataManager.class
/files.yml <- sitting in the root of "dependency" jar
```

Run as:

```
java -cp ./dependency.jar;./main.jar com.example.Main
```

Run result:

```
Feature file NOT PRESENT!!! <- which is not correct. File is there 
and there is no exceptions regarding closed stream.
```

So`new File(getFile())` and `classLoader.getResourceAsStream(getFile()))` they work differently. `File` by default uses absolute path and `classLoader.getResourceAsStream()` relative. I suggest you to use 
`classLoader.getResourceAsStream()` only and check if stream is `null` or not for file existence.

I recommend you to double check your dependency jar for `files.yaml` location. It might be nested inside of some directory.

Comment: My files.yaml is in the root of the Dependency.jar as i did a jar tvf...  I validated it by reading it using bufferedreader.  However you might be right that my insputstream might be null. But why?  Please see my update 2.